# Check if children components have their own children in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I was trying to check if the children (AssetExample2) of my parent (AssetExample) component have their own children. I would use this pattern for the splashscreen of the app that I'm building to hide when children have loaded but I can't seem to make it work as the state `hasChildren` that I created always returns `false` what am I doing wrong here?

[Snack runnable sample code](https://snack.expo.dev/ZvMD_Kl9R)

[image]

```js
// App.js

import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';
import AssetExample2 from './components/AssetExample2';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>
        I don't have children
      </Text>
      <Card>
        <AssetExample>
          <AssetExample2 />
        </AssetExample>
      </Card>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

```js
// AssetExample

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function AssetExample({children}) {
  const [hasChildren, setHasChildren] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      if (child.props.children) {
        setHasChildren(true);
      }
    }
  });
  }, [children]);

  return (hasChildren && 
    <View>
      <Text>
        I have children
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

```js
// AssetExample2

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function AssetExample2() {
  return (<View><Text>I exist</Text></View>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am checking the count of children since you did not want to check for any specific inner component. I have added the snack file for your [reference](https://snack.expo.dev/@revanthshalon/test)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function AssetExample(props) {
  const [hasChildren, setHasChildren] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    React.Children.count(props.children)? setHasChildren(true):setHasChildren(false);
  }, [props.children]);

  return (hasChildren && 
    <View>
      <Text>
        I have children
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What if I want to check for the inner children of the children as well? because I'm trying to implement this on a splashcreen for my app where the splashscreen component is inside the _layout file of my expo router so I'm trying to get let's say if the children of imported components like <Stack /> are already !null / loaded

Comment: What you can do is create a recursive function where you pass the children till you get to the point where children count is 0. Then set the state to update the splashScreen to hide once the criteria is satisfied.